# why is this sql not using index with date type column

Tags: mysql, innodb, groupwise-maximum

mysql:5.7/8.0

table ddl

```sql
-- auto-generated definition
create table test_date_index
(
    id  int auto_increment  primary key,
    account_id int not null,
    remark  varchar(10) null,
    cal_date date  null,
    constraint cal_date_index
    unique (cal_date, account_id)
);
```

in this case not using index

```sql
explain
select *
from test_date_index
where (account_id, cal_date) in (
    select account_id, max(cal_date) from test_date_index group by account_id
);
```

but work in this case

```sql
explain
select *
from test_date_index
where (account_id, cal_date) in (
    select account_id, '2022-04-18' from test_date_index group by account_id
)
```

i think this is because of the type of the `cal_date` column but i can't find any doc about this

Comment: see: [When should I use a unique constraint instead of a unique index?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/144/when-should-i-use-a-unique-constraint-instead-of-a-unique-index)   I was actually looking for the difference between `constraint` and `index`, but I could not find a better doc...

Comment: @Luuk - That link _happens_ to apply.  But _do not trust_ SQL Server advice when answering a MySQL question (and vice versa).  There are lots of differences between the two products.  This (Constraint vs Index) is a rare case where they are the same.

Comment: find that:
first query used materialize after optimized,second query used semi join after optimized. and materialize cann't use index

Answer (score 0):

What version are you using?  Before 5.7, "row constructors" were not optimized.  However, the lack of the optimal index may be the main cause of sluggishness.

For the first query...

Rewrite the "groupwise-max" query thus:

```
select  b.*
    FROM (  SELECT  account_id, max(cal_date) AS cal_date
            from  test_date_index
            group by  account_id  ) AS a
    JOIN  test_date_index AS b  USING(account_id, cal_date)
```

Get promote the `UNIQUE` index to this:

```
PRIMARY KEY(account_id, cal_date)
```

with those columns in that order.  Specificaly, `account_id` needs to be first in order to be useful in the "derived" query (subquery) that I used.  Also, it tends to be a better way to organize the table.

Your second query shows that it can use your backward index and that 'row constructors' are optimized in the version you are running.

Comment: i know rewrite is work. finally i want to know the reason why this query didn't work